# Css shape transition - bottom left

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm new to css transform styles. So I failed to figure out this matter. I've played with this code. But it have the corner on right side. But I need that corner shape in left side. Like this way. How can I create that? or any other methods for this kind of situations?

[image]

```css
div {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  color: beige;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.skew {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: tomato;
}
.skew:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}
.skew.bottom:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
.skew.bottom:after {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skewY(22deg);
}
.skew.bottom {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="skew bottom">Some content</div>
```

Comment: Change `transform: skewY(22deg)` to `transform: skewY(-22deg)`. Here is a good on the topic: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  color: beige;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.skew {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: tomato;
}
.skew:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}
.skew.bottom:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
.skew.bottom:after {
  top: 0px; /*CHANGED THIS*/
  left: 0px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skewY(-22deg);/*CHANGED THIS*/
}
.skew.bottom {
  margin-top: 100px; /*INCREASED THIS*/
}
```

```html
<div class="skew bottom">Some content</div>
```

#### Explanation

- From `bottom: 0px` to `top: 0px` : So that the `after` element starts at the top left corner of it's parent which is the `.skew` element itself.
- From `22deg` to `-22deg`: To rotate the `after` element counter clockwise. Since the `transform-origin` is set to `top left` it will rotate in a way that the left top corner of the `after` element aligns with the left top corner of the `.skew` element.
- From `margin-top: 0px` to `margin-top: 100px`: Because transforms do not change other elements around it or make space when a transformation takes some part of the element out of the view, it's necessary to have enough margin so that we can view the element after skewing it.